# Mongodb update array element wont work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

my json in db like this =

```
_id:21321213123, // req.body.analizId
updatedAt:...,
createdAt:...,
uploadedPhotos: [
   {
      photoId:12321311,
      isDeleted: false
   },
   ...
]
```

and my query is

```
update({_id: req.body.analizId, "uploadedPhotos.photoId":req.body.id}, {$set:{"uploadedPhotos.$.isDeleted":true}}).exec(function(err, d){ console.log(d)});
```

I want to update isDeleted field in uploadedPhotos relation to matched photoId in uploadedPhotos array
But the code doesnt work
how can i do this ?

Comment: The code looks okay to me. what error do you see ?

Comment: it does not show errors , log says { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }. It does not modify the field @Veeram

Comment: This is what I see. db.photos.update({_id: 21321213123, "uploadedPhotos.photoId":12321311}, {$set:{"uploadedPhotos.$.isDeleted":true}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

Comment: i figured it out , when i replace ObjectId(21321321) with 21321321 it works in query